# Is it appropriate to give hints to beginner programmers?

Tags: discussion, questions, comments, new-users

I noticed this question:

> the question in the picture I need help
>
> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YKOF.jpg)

I left a comment:

> Hint: If you read this page thoroughly docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#numbers you should be able to work it out.

I did not explain the problem with the post since another user had done so already.

But I am wondering whether it is wrong to leave a hint as I did, while it helps them (assuming they are complete beginners, and could really could not find an answer), does it harm the site and should I avoid this sort of thing in the future? - Or should it be encouraged even?

Since there was no MCVE, no attempt or any possible signs of any attempt, and nor do I think it will ever be of any use to future visitors, should this practice be avoided in the future?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well it's certainly not an *answer* so if you did post something like that as an answer (you didn't, so that's not an issue) then it would be a problem.

Honestly I wouldn't think of it as "hints".  I wouldn't use the word in a comment, and I wouldn't think of comments like those as hints.  That is a comment with a link to a resource related to the topic of the question that you think might contain information to help the question author with their problem.  That's an okay thing to post as a comment.  Maybe it helps the question author improve their question, maybe it helps them or someone else to construct an answer to the question, or maybe it's just tangentially useful information for the question author and others with a similar problem to read through.  All of this is fine for a comment.

Comment: Thank you.  So what I did is fine, just calling it a hint is the problem.

Comment: @Simon I don't think it makes the comment worse (or at least not dramatically). To me it's just noise at best.  I think it's hanging you up because of the implied intentions.  By posting a "hint" I get the feeling you're implying that you could have answered but that you choose not to, and instead choose to "only" provide a link to a resource with further information.  But whether that's true or not your reasons for posting it is irrelevant.  The comment is equally useful to any reader if you didn't know enough about it to answer and only linked because that's all you could do.

Comment: So I'd suggest leaving off the "hint" both so that you don't worry yourself about what the intentions are, and so that others don't try to read into them either.  If you have a helpful resources with further information that might be useful, provide said resource.

Comment: So something like "site x might be helpful to solve your problem" would be better?

Comment: @Simon Sure.  Again, these are pretty marginal changes.  I don't think the original comment is bad or meriting removal or anything like that, but if you're worried about people taking it the wrong way (which seems unlikely, but possible), I think that newer comment would address those concerns.

Comment: I have changed the comment to what I suggested above.

Comment: Another way to word it to make you feel better is "Have you read through _link_?" By posting this, it's almost as if you're seeking clarification while also hinting at the solution. This may be situational though

Comment: @Tas  Thank you.  That seems like another good approach.

Answer (score -1):

I have noticed in your screenshot that the submit button says "CHECK".

From my point of view, it is a Python programming learning application where beginners are first taught about the basics of Python and then self assessment (your image), not some kind of exam.

Since their ultimate target is teaching the concept, and your comment didn't provide them answer, but a source where he can learn to solve this type of questions. It should be encouraged.

Donate something in such a way that the beggar never need to beg again for that thing.

Show them the way to go instead of dropping there.

Comment: What do you mean by "dropping there"?

Answer (score -1):

If you help a person find the answer, you have given them an algorithm but not an answer.  They generated the answer.

If you cheat while doing that; yes, you gave them an answer.

That's why for homework problems and in my past life as a tutor, I never did the problem they had difficulty with; because, the odds of human nature are that it was always their graded homework.

As for the application you have a screenshot of, it's an android app meant to "help teach programming"  I've played around with it a bit, and honestly, it is not the most efficient way to learn programming, and the reward for completing it is about as worthless as a green check mark on a todo list.

Comment: +1 for identifying where it has come from (elusive to me since I don't use these applications  for learning programming) and for  the " it is not the most efficient way to learn programming" part